# Shinyjs functions not defined?

Tags: javascript, function, user-interface, shiny, shinyjs

I have tried to follow the documentation of Shinyjs to create a button that can hide a graph plot when it was clicked by the user in Shiny.

```
library("shiny")
library("quantmod")
library("data.table")
library("highcharter")
library("shinyjs")

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    highchartOutput("plot"),
    actionButton("btn", "Click me")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  ##Retrieve stock data
  stock_data <- getSymbols("IBM", auto.assign = FALSE)

  output$plot <- 
    renderHighchart({
      plot_max <- 200
      plot_min <- 100
        highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
          hc_yAxis_multiples(
            create_yaxis(2, height = c(200, 50), min = plot_min, max = plot_max, turnopposite = TRUE)
          ) %>% 
          # series :D
          hc_add_series_flags(stock_data, dates = as.Date("2018-10-12", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), title = "Testing flag", text = "some words") %>%
          hc_add_series(stock_data, yAxis = 0) %>% 
          hc_add_series(stock_data$IBM.Volume, yAxis = 1, type = "column", color = hex_to_rgba("green", 0.7))
      })

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    shinyjs::hide(id = "plot")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However when the button is clicked, the graph is not disabled. I have tested with other functions including shinyjs::disable() and the result is the same, with error messages such as "disable() not defined" showing up.

What can be done to fix this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: You have to add `useShinyjs()` just after `fluidPage`.

Comment: as per @StéphaneLaurent https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/useShinyjs.html

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you so much, it fixes the issue.